# Closed form of a definite integral with exponentials and trigonometric functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

I need to calculate the following integral:
$$I = \int_0^{\pi} \sin(x) e^{-\sqrt{1-\cos(x)}-\sqrt{1+\sin(x)}} dx$$
The numerical value is 0.22110767725647466402...
So far, I tried Maple and Inverse Symbolic Calculator (which found nothing).
[The plot of the integrand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cta0W.jpg)

Any hints about showing that it doesn't have a closed form solution will also be very much appreciated.

Comment: We have
$$ I = 2 \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin(2x)\exp\left[-\sqrt{2}\left(\sin(x)+\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right)\right]\,dx$$
or
$$ I = 2 \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin(2x) \exp\left[-\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{2}}\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{8}\right)\right]\,dx$$
that can be computed in terms of the [modified Bessel functions of the first kind][1] $I_2$, the [Struve functions][2] $L_0,L_1$ and the explicit values provided by
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin(2x)\exp\left[-A\sin(x)\right]\,dx = \frac{2e^{-A}(e^A-A-1)}{A^2}.$$

Comment: (moved to comments since some @à°ù# thought it was a good moment to practice his ability to downvote)

Comment: Yes once again (maybe the same) "serial killer". It's a pity. What could be done ? Is moderation to be reconsidered on this site ?

Comment: If you undelete your answer, I will upvote it, because it is very good.